# W3School Drag And Drop example not working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to add drop and drag features on a website. I am still learning about this and want to implement a prototype before adding it to my website.

I have found the [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) and it works fine on their website.

I have tried to move this example to JSFiddle to fiddle with it. Unfortunately, this example does not work [there](http://jsfiddle.net/3vKTS/1/). Does anyone know what the issue is?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<p>Drag image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <img id="drag1" src="http://iconbug.com/data/29/128/1cc6b61217921b624db0cd6cfd6d1360.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I had to use an image available from a public URL. I also added a closing `/` to the img tag.

**P.S.:** I want to avoid JQuery as much as possible.

Comment: Why am I not surprised? W3Schools is [awful resource](http://www.w3fools.com/) to learn web development, try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) instead.

Comment: change the no wrap-body in fiddle options  it works(as in site) here http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/zx8Ty/

Comment: Thanks Vinod. If you create an answer, I'll approve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the no wrap-body in fiddle options it works [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/zx8Ty/)

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: This code is exactly the same as in the question. Looks like the problem was in the Fiddle itself. Could you expand?

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript inclusion issue.

In Frameworks and extensions try setting the second dropdown to `No wrap - in <head>`

Worked for me.